# Importing modules and getting traceback errors in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, import, traceback

I'm trying to translate a pseudocode into a working Python file. The code, however small, has imported modules in it and I would like to stay as true to the original as I can. When I go to run the script I get an immediate traceback error after I input the first piece of data. I HAD ORIGINALLY INCLUDED THE PSEUDOCODE I WAS TRYING TO TRANSLATE FROM, BUT I THINK IT WAS CAUSING TOO MUCH CONFUSION SO I REMOVED IT.

```
#accepts ID number, name of agent, and the number of bedrooms
#outputs ID, name, and commission amount
#MY python code with modules.

#this was my way of trying to define variables
#so the main program would accept them.... instead of except them.
QUIT = 9999
commissionEarned = float
comm3 = float (100.00)
comm2 = float (75.00)
comm1 = float (55.00)
commStudio = float (30.00)
import getReady
while salesPersonID != 9999:
    import detailLoop
import finish
```

module getReady()

```
salesPersonID = float (raw_input ('Enter salesperson ID or 9999 to quit: '))
```

module detailLoop()

```
salesPersonName = float (raw_input ('Enter name: '))
numBedrooms = float (raw_input ('Enter number of bedrooms: '))
if numBedrooms >= 3:
    commissionEarned = comm3
elif numBedrooms == 2:
    commissionEarned = comm2
elif numBedrooms == 1:
    commissionEarned = comm1
else commissionEarned == commStudio
print salesPersonID, salesPersonName, commissionEarned
salesPersonID = float (raw_input ('Enter name: '))
```

module finish()

```
print 'End of Program'
break
```

THIS IS THE ERROR....IM SURE THERE ARE MORE.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
Enter salesperson ID or 9999 to quit: 1584
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\KirkandAngela\Desktop\Kirk\Find the bugs Ch4\DEBUG04-01.py",
line 8, in <module>
while salesPersonID != 9999:
NameError: name 'salesPersonID' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: I'm very new to this.  Are you saying that I can't call functions from a module into the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may not understand the usage of "import".

There are two way of accessing a variable(or whatever):
1.

```
import getReady

# you can getReady.salesPersonID
```

2.

```
from getReady import salesPersonID

#you can salesPersonID
```

In my personal view of point, these codes are not very pythonic. ^_^

Comment: Your probably right. I'm adding pseudo into the python and the hybrid doesn't seem to work well. At this stage I am really trying to concentrate more on the logic aspect. Although I think once I get a better grasp of python, I will enjoy working with it.